# Custom Protocol blocked By Chrome Version 30

Tags: google-chrome

When I try to launch a custom protocol from https connection, Chrome version 30 is giving the following error.

[blocked] The page at https://something.com ran insecure content from custom-protocol://somethingelse.com/myapp

Chrome version 29 works fine.

Did anyone come across similar issue?
Is this a new issue/feature in chrome?
Appreciate any response.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did, and the problem was that I was using https to access the page, the link was in an iframe and most of all, the certificate used in the https was not trusted. After moving to https works fine.

And by the way, it was working in FireFox.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with launching custom protocol URLs. This superuser question addresses this issue: http://superuser.com/questions/655405/custom-protocol-handler-not-working-in-chrome-on-ssl-page

Comment: Why do you say it has nothing to do with custom protocol?! I said that I was opening a custom protocol in a page accessed by HTTPS.

Comment: Sorry you're right. Yes, Chrome 30+ blocks iframes with custom protocols in documents transferred via HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for that, but still, I have a minus one in my answer!

Comment: I am sorry about that. It doesn't let me undo this. Unless you edit your answer :(

Edit: Do you mean "After moving to _HTTP_ it works fine."?